# Allowing 'anyone' executable permission on /usr/local/bin/docker-compose?

Tags: docker, permissions

The [docs on docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) instruct to add executable permissions for all users on docker-compose. That is, run:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

yielding

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7986086 Nov 24 18:05 /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Shouldn't 'everyone' be restricted from having executable permission?

Additional info: I run docker from a dockeruser that I added to the docker group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docker-compose binary itself is just a binary. Allowing any user on a system to run an installed application is fairly common practice. Compare the permissions of docker-compose to the ssh or ping binary, for example.

Being able to run the `docker-compose` binary doesn't mean that you have permissions to access the locally running docker daemon. You'd need rw access to the /var/run/docker.sock socket in order to do that.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for additional elaboration on docker daemon and /var/run/docker.sock socket!